# 3d surface of crop field with R

Tags: 3d, surface

I'm trying to produce a 3d surface plot of a crop field using data pulled from the yield monitor of a combine.

The data I have is

```
x = longitude 
y = latitude 
z = altitude (x, y, z)
```

I would also like to add coloring for the yield once I figure out the best way to plot the surface.

The original file is for 155 acres which has a little over 77,000 data points. Each acre is just over 500 data points. Creating a mesh file for the full field crashes my computer every time. Is there anything I can to allow my laptop to process a file the size of the whole field?

Also, what is the easiest way to plot this data? surface3d, persp, contour3d?

Comment: 77k data points is trivial. What's crashing? What SORT of crash? What's the error? Where's the source code? What have you tried so far? This is barely a question, and contains zero detail that would be valuable when providing a solution. Update your post with code and more information. I don't know what language you're using (C++? Freaking Mathematica? WebGL?) or anything else. Also, google GPlot.

Comment: I'm using R. When I try to create a matrix with the three variables, R throws an error saying: "cannot allocate vector of size 3406209.0 Gb" or my laptop will simply freeze.